# Accessing variable on button pressed

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using javafx to program a small board game, and I've created a grid for each 'cell' on the board.

However I'm having some issues changing the colour of a cell when the cell button is pressed.

Here's one of the errors I'm getting:
"Error:(44, 43) java: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final"

However, I can't make the variables final - since the variables are part of a for loop, as shown:

```
for (int columns = 0; columns < 8; columns++) {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < 8; rows++) {
            positions[columns][rows] = new Button();

            positions[columns][rows].setText("X:" + columns + " Y:" + rows); // current location text (temp)

            positions[columns][rows].setMinHeight(cellDimensions);
            positions[columns][rows].setMaxHeight(cellDimensions);
            positions[columns][rows].setMinWidth(cellDimensions);
            positions[columns][rows].setMaxWidth(cellDimensions);

            String zoneColour = getColourBoard(columns, rows);
            positions[columns][rows].setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + zoneColour + "; ");

            positions[columns][rows].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                            positions[columns][rows].setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFA500; ");
                        }
                    });

            grid.add(positions[columns][rows], columns, rows);

        }
    }
```

The real issue here is that I need to add an event handler to a button that is part of an array of buttons, but can't seem to be able to access counter variables for said button array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this problem because `columns` and `rows` change throughout the loop. You could make a final instance of these but it would make more sense to create a `final Button` to reference in your Listener.

```
for (int columns = 0; columns < 8; columns++) {
    for (int rows = 0; rows < 8; rows++) {
        positions[columns][rows] = new Button();
        positions[columns][rows].setText("X:" + columns + " Y:" + rows); // current location text (temp)
        positions[columns][rows].setMinHeight(cellDimensions);
        positions[columns][rows].setMaxHeight(cellDimensions);
        positions[columns][rows].setMinWidth(cellDimensions);
        positions[columns][rows].setMaxWidth(cellDimensions);

        String zoneColour = getColourBoard(columns, rows);
        positions[columns][rows].setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + zoneColour + "; ");

        final Button b = positions[columns][rows];
        // final int c = columns, r = rows;
        positions[columns][rows].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // Could use c and r above if needed.
                // positions[c][r]
                b.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFA500; ");
            }
        });
        grid.add(positions[columns][rows], columns, rows);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution completely fixed the issue, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to set the loop counter to a final variable immediately on each iteration.

```
for (int columns = 0; columns < 8; columns++) {
    final int columnNum = columns;
    for (int rows = 0; rows < 8; rows++) {
        final int rowNum = rows;
        // now use columnNum and rowNum
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is about the positions[columns][rows] reference inside the handle method you could try to replace it by event.getSource(), cast it to the correct type, to remove the reference to positions in there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a strange way to do it, but you could make a separate class

```
public class PositionEventHandler extends EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private final Button button;

    public PositionEventHandler(Button b) {
        this.button = b;
        b.setOnAction(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        this.button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFA500; ");
    }
}
```

It would make more sense if you passed in `"#FFA500"` as a parameter as like a `String clickColor`

---

And then, in the loop.

```
final Button b = new Button();

b.setText("X:" + columns + " Y:" + rows);

new PositionEventHandler(b); // One line to define the action onto itself. 

positions[columns][rows] = b;
```